# How to reset KDE wallet password in linux?

Tags: kde, password, kwallet

I have installed OpenSUSE on my laptop. I am trying to connect to my wifi.
I entered my wifi password (correctly) and then it is asking for my KDE wallet password. I set the KDE password but forgot it.

Is there any way to reset it or do I have to reimage my laptop?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/22154/how-to-reset-a-password-from-kwallet

Answer (score 18):

You can just remove the wallet instead. Next time a new password will be asked.

```
cd $(kde4-config --localprefix)share/apps/kwallet
mv kdewallet.kwl kdewallet.kwl.bak
```

(if your wallet is called kdewallet.kwl)

Comment: Works on Ubuntu too!

Comment: Tried on Debian in 2018, apparently wallets have been moved to conform with the XDG base directory specification. I found mine in `~/.local/share/kwalletd/`.

Answer (score 7):

- Backup your existing wallet

> ```
> cd $HOME/.local/share/kwalletd/ 
> BACKUP_DATE=$(date +"%F-%X")
> mv kdewallet.kwl "kdewallet.kwl-${BACKUP_DATE}.bak"
> mv kdewallet.salt "kdewallet.salt-${BACKUP_DATE}.bak"
> ```

- Create your new wallet, and if all is OK, optionally remove those two backup files.

Like @FrontierPsycho hinted, wallets have been moved to conform with the XDG base directory specification. Confirmed for KDE on Debian Buster and Ubuntu bionic, too.
(This is just moving comment to an answer, including the salt file)

Comment: In Ubuntu 20 BACKUP_DATE gets set to include a space.  So the move commands need their targets quoted.