# Disable KDE Wallet from the command line

Tags: kde, kwallet

When I log into my desktop session, Plasma shell is unresponsive and CPU utilization is 100%. I have tracked this down to an issue with KDE Wallet and an attempt to make a WiFi connection. Unfortunately, I cannot resolve the issue via the desktop session because it is mostly unresponsive.

I am seeking a command line solution. I can log in via SSH or I can log into the console without SDDM & Plasma.

I saw a similar solution here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/36444/15010

```
cd $(kde4-config --localprefix)share/apps/kwallet mv kdewallet.kwl
kdewallet.kwl.bak
```

However, I do not have a directory at `~/.kde4/share/apps/kwallet`

The closest I find is `~/.kde/share/apps/kwallet` where I have I see only this one file: `kdewallet.salt`

find . -iname "*wallet*"

```
./.config/kwalletrc
./.config/kwalletmanager5rc
./.kde/share/apps/kwallet
./.kde/share/apps/kwallet/kdewallet.salt
./.kde/share/config/kwalletrc
./.kde4/share/config/kwalletrc
./.local/share/kwalletd
./.local/share/kwalletd/kdewallet.salt
```

Comment: Going out on a limb, but would uninstalling the wallet w/o removing dependencies help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a couple of options:

```
pkill kwallet
```

to kill the current wallet processes.  If your desktop is still unresponsive, change `Enabled=false` in `~/.config/kwalletrc` and log out and back in.

On a side note, you can open the wallet configuration with `kcmshell5 kwalletconfig5`, but it crashes without a gui.

Comment: I think this is probably the right answer. Unfortunately, it did not work for me. After changing `~/.config/kwalletrc`, kwallet continues to pop up and cause problems when I log in.

Answer (score 4):

For KDE4:

```
kwriteconfig --file kwalletrc --group 'Wallet' --key 'Enabled' 'false'
kwriteconfig --file kwalletrc --group 'Wallet' --key 'First Use' 'false'
```

For KDE5:

```
kwriteconfig5 --file kwalletrc --group 'Wallet' --key 'Enabled' 'false'
kwriteconfig5 --file kwalletrc --group 'Wallet' --key 'First Use' 'false'
```

Source:

```
# Kwallet is annoying, and also makes connecting
# to wireless networks take multiple attempts -- no thanks.
```

https://github.com/ryanpcmcquen/linuxTweaks/blob/e60f2421a3b98c7741a0b27cfe176db10e130a1f/.kdeSetup.sh#L18

Related:

[Disable KWallet password request in Arch Plasma 5](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196522/disable-kwallet-password-request-in-arch-plasma-5)

https://askubuntu.com/questions/47216/how-to-disable-kde-wallet

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29594260/how-to-disable-kwallet-in-kde-plasma-5

https://superuser.com/questions/994551/disable-kwallet-popups-from-chrome